# Java Random sequence

Tags: java, random, bit-manipulation, sequence

Let me try my best to explain my problem, well, say we have a `Random` class constructed with a specific seed. At this point we can use the `.next()` methods to get the next value derived from the seed.

I seem to need a way to get values from this sequence, but not in order. For example, if Random had a method like `.get(X)` which would return whatever the value would be on the Xth invocation of `.next()`.

One way I can think of is to use a `for` loop X times, calling `.next()` on each cycle but not assigning a variable. This won't work well because of A. performance and B. it leaves the Random sequence at X, meaning if your next X is less than the original X, you'll have to reconstruct the `Random`.

Here's another way I thought of to solve this problem. Maybe you can derive a temporary new seed from the old seed and X, invoke `next()` one time and store the value, and then return the `Random` to its original seed. I don't know the typical way of getting this new seed out of two values, probably some crazy bitwise operations. All of my experimenting with this method has not been sufficiently random.

Well, thanks for helping!

Comment: you are chasing a false goal. In a good random generator, .next() is undistinguishable from .get(X). If standard Random is good enough for you, you need not .get(X). If it is not, .get(X) would be as bad as .next().

Comment: how u have concluded that using for loop method will not work because of performance and (B) reason in your question?

Comment: Absolutely no reason for close. Perfect question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a cache for your Random object. What I mean is create an ArrayList that is initially empty. Then create the get(X) method that uses both the ArrayList and the Random object. When get(X) is called, you call Random's next() method X times and write the X values it generates into the ArrayList. Then return the last value.

The next time get() is called with parameter Y, you compare Y to the length of your ArrayList. If it is less than the length of the list (Y is smaller than X), then you have already computed that value earlier, and you can look it up in the ArrayList and return it. If Y is larger than the length of the list, then you grow the ArrayList by calling Random's next() method enough times to get to Y.

You'll need some memory, but it will let you go back, and the running time will be as slow as the largest X you ever see.

Comment: An even easier way is to pre-generate a whole bunch of random numbers (as many as you will ever need in your program) and store them in an array. Then simply look them up in the array when you need them.

Comment: That is a good idea, and so far I like yours the best for sure. I did do a little bit of searching, and I found this similar (I think, not sure if his purpose is even close to mine) question:   bit.ly/1hu6T59   Do you think the code in that answer might give me my desired effect?

Answer (score -2):

A friend of mine once told me that we can't really have random values in Computers as any random value generation method will be based on a logical algorithm.

```
import java.util.Random;

Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

// Example
int randomInt = random.nextInt(500); [Returns value between 0(inclusive) and 500 (exclusive)]
And so goes the other methods.
```

Since time doesn't repeat, calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` and passing it as the Random seed would be your best bet. Its most common to do so.

In any way, you'd still be getting a pseudo-random number, no matter what algorithm you use.
You have to observe a physical process to obtain a really random number.

Comment: -1 The question asks about preseeded sequence generator, no physical randomness has been requested

Comment: Read the question please, seed _should not_ be random!

Comment: Since when time seed became random? :D But honestly and sincerely speaking, I can't see anywhere in the question, where the OP has said that seed shouldn't be random.

Comment: "say we have a Random class constructed with a specific seed"and how specific is execution time?

Comment: Yeah "specific seed" which means (according to me) any seed that the programmer has specified. My sincere opinion is that `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the one of the best possible seed that a programmer can provide, since time never repeats. A pre-seeded sequence can be generated by its help then.